# How can I create a void return statement in a Groovy AST transformation?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I am building an AST transformation that generates a `void` method. I want to check whether the value passed in is already equal to another value, and if so, exit early. The code would ordinarily look like this:

```
if(param.is existing) {
    return
}
```

The `ReturnStatement` class has a property `returningNullOrVoid` that checks to see whether the return expression is `null`, so I tried the obvious approach:

```
ifS(sameX(paramEx, existingEx), returnS(constX(null))
```

This produced an exception when compiling the transformed class:

```
BUG! exception in phase 'instruction selection' in source unit 'Annotated.groovy' Unexpected return statement at -1:-1 return null
```

How can I insert the return statement for the early exit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ReturnStatement` class has a constant named `RETURN_NULL_OR_VOID`:

```
/**
 * Only used for synthetic return statements emitted by the compiler.
 * For comparisons use isReturningNullOrVoid() instead.
 */
public static final ReturnStatement RETURN_NULL_OR_VOID = new ReturnStatement(ConstantExpression.NULL);
```

The Groovy compiler checks for this specific instance to generate a void `return;`. When creating an AST statement block that includes a return statement, your statement *is* "a synthetic return statement emitted by the compiler", and you should use that constant:

```
ifS(sameX(paramEx, existingEx), ReturnStatement.RETURN_NULL_OR_VOID)
```